# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 php mysql web application crashes on last insert call

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having quite the frustrating issue with my POS system php web application. I'll only include the error to keep it short.

MySQL database consists of a `customer`, `order`, and `orderline` tables (all you need to know for the error i'm getting). When I run the below PHP script, it crashes at the line that has a comment saying ERROR. My customer table has an auto increment PK called customerid, that is why I have a 1 when inserting into orderline because of the previous insert.

```
require 'connect.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (customerid, fname, lname)
            VALUES (123456789, 'Dan', 'Dentin')";
$pdo->exec($sql);


$dt = new DateTime();
$dt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (date, customerid)
            VALUES ('$dt', 123456789)";
$pdo->exec($sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO orderline (orderid, sprice, `status`)
            VALUES (1, 5647, 'PAID')";
$pdo->exec($sql);  //ERROR IT CRASHES HERE ON MY LAST INSERT CALL
```

The error says:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails FOREIGN KEY (`orderid`) REFERENCES `order` (`customerid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I am very confused as to why i cannot insert my orderline information, if more info is needed please say so.

Comment: How do you know that your newly inserted order will get the ID of 1?

Comment: You also seem to have related the orderid field in the orderline table with the customer id field in the order table.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I know it will get ID of 1 because order table is empty and that is the very first entry which then the auto incrementing PK of the order table will be 1 as it is the first entry.

Comment: @CP_nate that's not necessarily the case. Auto increment value may be different from 1 even if the table is empty.

Comment: @Shadow before executing the script i am making sure that i TRUNCATE the order table so that it will always start at 1.

Comment: unsure as to why i was downvoted, explain for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES order (customerid)` in the error message indicates that you related the `orderline.orderid` field with the `order.customerid` field. This results in mysql trying to match `1` with `123456789`, yielding the error you described.

You should change the foreign key to relate to the `id` field in the `order` table (whatever the name of the primary key in the `order` table is).

Comment: I think this is correct, currently trying to fix my database creation script.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you so much i see now that i should not be relying on MySQL workbenches forward engineering from my ER diagram.